# What is the difference between a mixture model and a multimodal distribution?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, mixture-distribution, mode

A distribution that is a "Mixture model" has a very similar definition as a "multimodal" distribution.

Wikipedia Says:

> a **multimodal distribution** is a continuous probability distribution with two or more mode

Now to compare:

> In statistics, a **mixture model** is a probabilistic model for representing the presence of subpopulations within an overall population, without requiring that an observed data set should identify the sub-population to which an individual observation belongs.

What is the difference between the two? They sound like they are the same thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complement @matt's answer, you can also consider the [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with $\alpha = .5$ and $\beta = .5$.  It is illustrated by the red line in the figure below (copied from Wikipedia).  As you can see, it is multimodal (viz., bimodal), but it isn't a mixture distribution:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Imagine a scenario where two distributions (e.g., two univariate normals) have the same mean, but different variances. In this example, they together form a unimodal distribution from a mixture of two different populations.

Comment: Ohh, nice! But in most cases, a multimodal distribution would be a mixture modal, right?

Comment: @zero if you persist is spelling "model" as "modal" it's not surprising you're getting confused with "multimodal". (I fixed your title but you're also typing it in comments)

Comment: lol - I'm fixing that.